# Drag and Drop Unity Dash 11.10

Tags: 11.10, unity, unity-dash, drag-and-drop

Why is dragging and dropping applications in the Ubuntu 11.10 Unity Dash so laggy? It wasn't like this in 11.04.

Comment: it aint laggy for me, what are your system specs? unity 3d or 2d?

Comment: Unity 3D, NVIDIA GeForce 8400 GS, 2GB Memory, Intel® Pentium(R) D CPU 2.80GHz × 2, 32 bit.

Comment: hm well that should work. which graphics driver do you have?

Comment: NVIDIA's  post-release up dates. Tried all possible graphics drivers. All were the same.

Comment: This has already been posted as a [bug on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/851172) and is hence offtopic. If you are still affected, please see this bug and mark yourself as affected if you have a Launchpad account. Thanks!